# Simple modification to a counter script that adds based on timer than page visiting

Tags: php

Hello my goal is to modify this following script to add +1 based on a timer than on page visiting.

What I mean, the timer must add +1 visitor on every 20 minutes. If it is possible it would be great to add +1 on a random time between 15 to 20 minutes.

Then the result will be present in the page. Here is the code

```
<?php 

$File = "counter.txt"; //the file
$handle = fopen($File, 'r+') ;
$data = fread($handle, 512) ; //get the number on the counter
$count = $data + 1; //Add 1
print "You are visitor number ".$count; //Prints it on page
fseek($handle, 0) ; //puts the pointer back to the begining 
fwrite($handle, $count) ; //saves it
fclose($handle) ; //close it

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to forge the statistics, right? The result would be 3 visitors per hour, is that what you want?

Comment: @Tim Yes, this is the expected result...

Comment: @Tim but I prefer on a random period just to make it a bit better if it's possible.

Comment: `<?php print "You are visitor number ".rand(10000,1000000); ?>` :)

Comment: Oh you are a great programmer! So, don't you have anything else to pass your time?

Comment: Sorry about that... As Delan already said, it can't be done from PHP because the script runs only when someone visits and is terminated afterwards. You'll need a scheduled task to visit the site. Alternatively, you can do $count = $data + rand(1,3); so that each visit increments the counter with a random number between 1 and 3.

Comment: Thank you sir, I guess that this is a more appropriate answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to have the script running not as part of a page request, i.e. on the command line either with an external task scheduler (like anacron) or have it running all the time, sleeping for the delay time and doing the counting in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there an example anywhere?